# how to hide a media controller when a video starts in android?

Tags: android, video, back-button, mediacontroller

I'm trying to play a video with the media controller sets to invisible, so when I override the back key, the video stops and the activity finishes. But, when I press the back button before spending three seconds, I need press the button twice, because the media controller is activated. So, how to hide the media controller when the video starts?

```
private void playRecording() {
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

    video_view.setMediaController(mc);
    video_view.setVideoPath(output_file_name);

    video_view.start();

    mc.show(0);
    mc.hide();
}

private void stopPlayingRecording() {
    video_view.stopPlayback();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (is_playing) {
            stopPlayingRecording();
        }

        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the video is started you can try.

```
video_view.setMediaController(null);
```

then if you want to show it again when a user presses on the screen you could implement a ontouchevent that will create one and show it for a few seconds and then set it back to null again